# VBA to Match word by word from a cell to word by word in an another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to match each an every word in column A to each and every word in column B. In other words, I want to check if the words of column A are present in column B. If yes, then highlight the same in Column B.

I have tried the below code, but this looks for an exact match.

```
 
Dim xStr As String
    Dim i, Y As Variant
    Dim M, j As Long
```

count = Range("A4", Range("A4").End(xlDown)).Rows.count

For i = 4 To count + 3
    xStr = Range("B" & i).value
       With Range("G" & i)
        .Font.ColorIndex = 1
        For j = 1 To Len(.Text)
            If Mid(.Text, j, Len(xStr)) = xStr Then .Characters(j, Len(M)).Font.ColorIndex = 3
        Next j
      End With

 Next i

Example :

Column A# BAND AID WASHPROOF 
Column B## Johnson & Johnson Washproof Antiseptic Adhesive Band-Aid (Jar)

The 3 words in column A should be highlighted in column B.

Comment: You can use [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) after Splitting the text in Column A and Finding them word by Word.

Comment: So Basically split the cell value and save it in array. Now loop through each element of array and use Find function to locate that word in column B.

Comment: Are the 3 words "BAND AID WASHPROOF" of your example within one cell (e. g. B4) or within 3 cells in column B (e. g. B4, B5, B6)? In other words: Do you want to compare whole columns or cell-pair by cell-pair?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to compare the words in B4 with G4, then B5 with G5 and so on - each pair individually.

If you `Split` the content of your cell with space as delimiter, then you have its words within an array and can compare each array element.

```
Private Sub CompareWords()
    Dim xStr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 4 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            xStr = Split(.Cells(i, "B").Value, " ")
            With .Cells(i, "G")
                .Font.ColorIndex = 1
                For x = LBound(xStr()) To UBound(xStr())
                    For y = 1 To Len(.Text)
                        If Mid(.Text, y, Len(xStr(x))) = xStr(x) Then
                            .Characters(y, Len(xStr(x))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        End If
                    Next y
                Next x
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.. This kind of does the job. But it is case sensitive. The capital letter word and small letter word should be considered same. Is there anything i can do to include that ?

Comment: That is also solved by putting "Option Compare Text" at the top. Thank you so much again for your help...

Comment: ... or by `If StrComp(a, b, vbTextCompare) = 0`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/strcomp-function)