# Compare words split by space in column A to strings in column B and return match if all the words in column A are present in any string in column B

Tags: excel, vba, split, compare, match

Document image
[image]

In the first cell there is text "Wei J 2020".
The VBA code should search for all the words in this text "Wei", "J" and "2020" in all the string present in column B.
If all these words are present in one string, it should highlight the text in column A which defines that it is a match.

All the words in A1 are matching with the string in B2.

```vb
Private Sub CompareWords()

    Dim xStr() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            xStr = Split(.Cells(i, "A").Value, " ")
            With .Cells(i, "B")
                For x = LBound(xStr()) To UBound(xStr())
                    For y = 1 To Len(.Text)
                        If Mid(.Text, y, Len(xStr(x))) = xStr(x) Then
                            .Characters(y, Len(xStr(x))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        End If
                    Next y
                Next x
            End With
        Next i
    End With 
End Sub
```

I am able to compare the words in A1 with B1, A2 with B2 and so on.
Result if string is present in same row
[image]

But the requirement is to find the words in A1 in all the strings present in column B, and return a match only if all the words are present in the same string.

Also this code changes the font color to red in column B if it is a match.
Can we instead highlight the word in column A if it is a match?

Comment: Do you have markdown sampledata to work with? Also what about formulae to solve this? And, what about any of these substring being part of a larger substring, in other words: false-positives. In your sample you found 'J' in 'MJ'.

Comment: What do you mean by "if all the words are present in the same string"? It would be good to also post a picture showing **how would you like the range to look after processing**.

Comment: If you copy code 1:1, it is nice to give at least a link to the author. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56581646/7599798

Comment: Do you really need an answer, a solution to your problem? Are you able to answer the clarification question I placed more than an hour before?

Comment: @JvdV Please find the link to the workbook below https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l1bsSSf1gZmkXxDTIt3Hr2OwfMj8QFqf/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106451064480627813940&rtpof=true&sd=true,   Also, false-postive results are rare as a match is only returned when each word (eg: "Wei" "J" and "2020") is present in one of the strings in column B

Comment: @FaneDuru, It means that if all the words separated by space are present individually in one of the strings of column B, it should then return a match https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l1bsSSf1gZmkXxDTIt3Hr2OwfMj8QFqf/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106451064480627813940&rtpof=true&sd=true, Please find the document from the, it contains two sheets (one is the sample worksheet and other one is the expected results)

Comment: @FunThomas, Apologies, I missed adding credits in the initial post, thank you for sharing the original code

Comment: Then, test the adapted code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next adapted code. It will check the same split string from a cell in A:A against all cells in B:B and color in yellow the cell where a full match has  been found (the words order does not matter):

```
Sub CompareWords()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, xStr() As String, arrMtch() As String, arrAddress() As String, rngYellow As Range
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lastR = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arrAddress(1 To lastR, 1 To 1) 'array to keep the addresses of cells from B:B where a match has been found
    
    'reset the columns appearence:
    ws.Range("A1:A" & lastR).Interior.Color = xlNone
    ws.Range("B1:B" & ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    ws.Range("C1:C" & ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With ws
        For i = 1 To lastR
            xStr = Split(.Cells(i, "A").Value, " ")
            For j = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
                With .Cells(j, "B")
                    ReDim arrMtch(UBound(xStr)) 'redim the array keeping "OK" for all matches
                    For x = LBound(xStr()) To UBound(xStr())
                        For y = 1 To Len(.Text)
                            If Mid(.Text, y, Len(xStr(x))) = xStr(x) Then
                                 arrMtch(x) = "OK"
                            End If
                        Next y
                    Next x
                    If UBound(Filter(arrMtch, "OK", True)) = UBound(arrMtch) Then 'if all array elements are "OK"
                        addToRange rngYellow, ws.Cells(i, "A") 'place the cell in a Union range
                        arrAddress(i, 1) = .Address                       'place the cell from B:B address in the dedicated array
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End With
            Next j
        Next i
    End With
    If Not rngYellow Is Nothing Then rngYellow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    ws.Range("C1").Resize(UBound(arrAddress), 1).Value = arrAddress
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True: Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above code writes in C:C column the address of the cell in B:B, where a match has been found.

Please, copy the next event code in the respective sheet code module. When execute a **double click** on a (yellow) cell from A:A, the matching cell from B:B is colored (in red) on the matching words:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        If Target.Offset(, 2) <> "" Then
               Dim xStr() As String, x As Long, y As Long
                xStr = Split(Target.Value, " ")
                With Me.Range(Target.Offset(, 2).Value)
                        .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'color the cell font in black
                        For x = LBound(xStr()) To UBound(xStr())
                            For y = 1 To Len(.Text)
                                    If Mid(.Text, y, Len(xStr(x))) = xStr(x) Then
                                        .Characters(y, Len(xStr(x))).Font.ColorIndex = 3
                                    End If
                                Next y
                        Next x
                        .Select
                End With
                Cancel = True
         End If
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer  @FaneDuru, but the code you have provided is comparing   each word in the split strings against all the cells in column B to provide individual matches, but as per my request all the words in the split string (like "Wei", "J" and "2020") should be searched for in column B:B, but it should show a match only when all the 3 words are present in the same string in one of the cells in column B. I hope you are able to understand...please see the below image (expected result) for your reference https://imgur.com/a/p3iOEWq

Comment: Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/53u0d7) a sample workbook having a button on its unique sheet. Pressing it the range is processed as (I understood) you need. I mean, the cells from A:A having a (complete) match in B:B is colored in yellow and the address of the matching cell form B:B is written in C:C. Double clicking on a yellow cell from A:A, will highlight the words in corresponding matching cell from B:B. The link is valid for 7 days...

Comment: The code works perfectly, you have provided me with more than I asked for. Thank you so much, I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Tan Glad I could help! 1. It is good to learn that a good question is the one helping us to clearly understand what you try accomplishing. Your question was not so good, from this point of view, at least, on my taste... 2. Making some tests I observed that for some cases there may be more than one occurrence in B:B. Now, the code exists the loop (B:B cells) after finding the first. Would it be useful to return as many occurrences the conde finds? I mean, their addresses in C:C. The code will be a little slower, but this can be done. Also, the double click event to run on more addresses in C:C

Comment: @Tan And something else: As new user here, I would like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue, will know that the provided solution works...

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, additionally..only the first occurrence data would suffice

Comment: The CompareWords module can be used as an add-in, but is there a way to automatically insert the "Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick" sheet code module in a sheet whenever a new workbook is opened, because currently I have to copy and paste it every time a new workbook or sheet is opened

Comment: @Tan Theoretically, it is possible. Not to copy the sheet module, **to programmatically write such an event code in a sheet module** of another workbook. But  I do not think this is good to be done. Firstly, all workbooks in discussion must be of the type `xlsm`, `xlsb`, `xlsa` to accept macros and processing of such files (through an add-n) it is good to be done on any workbook. So, there are two options (in my opinion): 1. To programmatically write the event code **only in a specific sheet**, if it is of the `xlsm` type and have a sheet named as "Whatewer".

Comment: 2. To adapt the code to act on active sheet - active cell, when **press a specific add-in button**. If you decide one of the two options (or a third one...), please place a new question posting the above code event and explaining what you want. If you tag me (here, with a link to the new question) I will try helping, if available. If no enough availability, maybe somebody else will help you with a solution...